# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, but I don't use that library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API service I'm hosting in IIS 7. When I make a call to that service, I get this error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundExceptionCould not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolver.GetControllerTypes(IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.WebHostHttpControllerTypeResolver.GetControllerTypes(IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerTypeCache.InitializeCache()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()

 Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolver.GetControllerTypes(IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.WebHostHttpControllerTypeResolver.GetControllerTypes(IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerTypeCache.InitializeCache()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at 
 System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.InitializeControllerInfoCache()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()

 Exception rethrown at [1]: 
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncInternal(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)</StackTrace></Exception>
```

I've looked all throughout my solution and projects, but I don't have any references to the ReportViewer. Does anybody have any idea why I'd be getting this error? From the error, it looks like it's doing a runtime load of the library. Is the ReportViewer needed  from System.Web.Http?

Comment: Check to see if you're using a library that has a dependency on `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms`. I'd start by looking at `System.Lazy1.LazyInitValue()`. Is that your own class? Probably not a good idea to put it in the System namespace.

Comment: From the `RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes` call, it looks like this is being invoked from a MEF wire-up. System.Web.Http does not need this. You might need to check any DLL's that you're accessing through MEF. You can try using the [FusLogVw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx) tool to identify which library is not linking properly.